# Branded Map with the commercial api

Tags: glympse

I noticed in the commercial API you have the ability to use branded map skins.  How is that actually implemented on the app side? Are there "MapView" objects exposed?  The commercial API documentation is not available online, but I would love to read it before I commit to purchasing a contract.  I'm really interested in what is exposed by the REST Api also.

Answer (score 0):

Glympse map branding is currently available only in the HTML-based Glympse viewer (i.e. a customizable experience for invite recipients or when viewing a Glympse group). There are a number of themable components, most of which are available with any registered Glympse app.

Unfortunately, the customizable map experience on the app side of things has not yet been released.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on branding the HTML Glympse viewer?